# How to install Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa remotely with virt-instlall?

Tags: system-installation, 20.04

`virt-install` does not accept the URL for remote installation I have found so far:

```
Could not find an installable distribution at 'http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/'
```

What is the proper URL for 20.04?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this, so might be missing the point but if was going to point you to a url to use for this, I would point you here http://archive.ubuntu.com/ then here for Focal http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-z-systems/+bug/1872941